# bootstrap form validation button redirection

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have create a simple form validation which uses  validator.js

What actually happens after the user presses the register button data is sent and user stays on the same page.

What i really want to get  is that after user pressing register button it will be redirected to  other page that is info.html which shows the message thank you for registration, Check mail for confirmation etc.

Here is the button I want to have a redirect function

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                          Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried this in the following way

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="register100-form-btn">
        <a class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" href="/info.html">Submit</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

it's now redirecting it to the other page but without a check validation form
All fields can remain empty which makes no sense for register form.

Comment: use javascript -> onclick and location.href

Comment: Show us a minimal example of the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to add a click event listener to the button and redirect to your desired view once clicked. Have your html as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

and then the following JS,

```
 document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
     let url = "http://mybaseurl/info.html"
     window.location.href = url;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but it did not give results now it also redirects but without field check.